# Save different variables from input dialog

Tags: java, variables, save

I am new to programming and I'm currently trying to solve this program. There should be an input dialog where the user can write different numbers until the user press the "cancel" button.

I used a `do-while` loop to get the input dialog popping up every time the user press OK but how do I save each and every number that the user writes?

When the user press CANCEL the program should show a message dialog where the highest and lowest number should be published. My current program looks like this,

```
public class Övning5komma91 {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int knappNr;
    int n;
    String s;
    do {
        s = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Skriv ett nummer");
        n = Integer.parseInt(s);
    } while (s != null && s.length() > 0);


  }

}
```

Comment: This isn't really an [mcve] but it is unclear what you really want to do here. If you actually have GUI components and click handlers, then those handlers should invoke code that does what you need. Though, it is unclear what the difference is between OK and Cancel handlers. Think about the part of your code that handles the data, and the part that shows the results and takes input. As it stands I think this question is a bit too broad for SO.

Comment: @jdv, your statement is not entirely correct. `JOptionPane.showInputDialog` is a valid GUI input, and it will return the entered value or null. The OP's program runs fine (well, except for the NPE on a user cancel and the parse of the null, but that is part of learning Java).

Comment: *shrug* it still isn't much of a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

To save all of the numbers, you will need to put them into a data structure. If the number of entries is not known *a priori*, then using `List<Integer> enteredNums = new ArrayList<>();` and then `if (s != null) { enteredNums.add(Integer.parseInt(s); }` would allow you to accumulate each entered number.

You can then process the entered numbers by:

```
for (Integer num : enteredNums) {
   ...
}
```

Edit based on comment:

There were two questions that the OP asked:

> 1. how do I save each and every number that the user writes?
> 2. how a message dialog where the highest and lowest number should be published.

Now logically #2 can be solved if one tracks #1, but in the comment collecting the actual data seems less important.

So, here is a different approach. If the primary goal is to track the largest and the smallest, and accumulation of all entered values is not really a requirement), then creating a couple of variables and conditionally setting them will work. After each entry, update the smallest, largest, and (here, for fun) total sum.

Without a data structure (like a List) it is not possible to accomplish #1, but assuming the real desire is #2, then it is not necessary to track all of the input, just the current smallest and largest.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   // the smallest entered number
   int smallest = 0;

   // the largest entered number
   int largest = 0;

   // the total; since lots of ints could overflow an int, use a long; not
   // completely immune to overflow, of course
   long sum = 0L;

   // whether it is the first entered number
   boolean foundOne = false;

   int n;
   String s;
   do {
      // get an input
      s = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Skriv ett nummer");

      // have to ensure not canceled; as s will be null
      if (s != null) {
        // parse the entered value; note this will throw an exception if
        //   cannot parse     
        n = Integer.parseInt(s);

        // on the first go through, we set unconditionally; also update
        //  the boolean so can indicate if anything was entered
        if (! foundOne) {
          smallest = n;
          largest = n;
          foundOne = true;
        }
        else {
          // set the smallest and the largest entered values
          //  the Math methods are just easier to read, but could
          //  be done by if statements
          smallest = Math.min(smallest, n);
          largest = Math.max(largest, n);
        }

        // add to the running total
        sum += n;
      }
} while (s != null && s.length() > 0);

// output the smallest, largest, total if anything entered
if (foundOne) {
  // this should be a dialog, rather than just output, but that is left
  //   as an exercise for the reader
  System.out.printf("The smallest value was %d\n", smallest);
  System.out.printf("The largest value was %d\n", largest);
  System.out.printf("The total of all entered values was %d\n", sum);
}
else {
  System.out.println("no values were entered");
}
```

}

Note: not tested

Comment: Since I am new to Java I don't really understand what you write about haha. I am following a step by step book and so far I've only read about how to use numbers, strings, if, while (do-while, break, for). Do you know how I can solve this problem with these tools? :)

Comment: @RobinJörgensen, I made some edits. You can solve _part_ of the question with just numbers (though I used a boolean in the code to allow separating out if an individual didn't enter anything). With some abuse of a `String`, one could accumulate every entered number and then print them out, but it isn't worth learning such a bad approach IMHO. So, the edit basically shows how to track smallest and largest entered values.

Comment: Thank you very much! I understand what you wrote in that code :)

Comment: Glad it helped. Please do consider accepting the answer.